# How to test a IAppSettings in ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack there is an IAppSettings as follows:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
DateTime lastUpdate = appSettings.Get<DateTime>("LastUpdated");
IList<string> allowedUsers = appSettings.GetList("AllowedUsers");
var redisConf = appSettings.Get<RedisConfig>("RedisConf");
```

How can I create an instance of AppSettings with properties in code?

I want to create a IAppSettings in code for testing and not to take the values from a configuration file, e.g., web.config.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a mocking framework like [moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) to stub out the implementation of the `IAppSettings` interface:

```
var appSettings = new Mock<IAppSettings>();
appSettings.Setup(s => s.Get<DateTime>("LastUpdated")).Returns(new DateTime(2015, 2, 1));
```

Then, in your test, just pass `appSettings.Object` to any service/component that needs an `IAppSettings`.

Answer (score 2):

The different `IAppSettings` providers are listed [AppSettings Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings), e.g. the [DictionarySettings](https://docs.servicestack.net/appsettings#dictionarysettings) lets you populate the settings from a .NET `Dictionary<string,string>`.

The [AppSettingsTests](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Configuration/AppSettingsTests.cs) will also be helpful to see how to test different AppSettings providers.